# pass binary image to a modal using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code that works just fine when passing data from a view to a modal. however i am now trying to pass a binary image to a modal and it isnt working. the image displays as a jpeg in the view and that is what i need to be in the modal as well.

View

```
  <h4 style="color: #3953a5; font-size:22px;"><strong>{{item.ItemName}}</strong></h4>
    <a ng-click="getIceDesignImage('data:image/jpg;base64,'+item)"><img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+item.Image}}" style="height:150px; width:150px;" alt="post img" class="pull-left img-responsive thumb margin10 img-thumbnail"></a>

    <h5 style="font-size:18px"><strong>${{item.ItemPrice}}</strong></h5>
    <article>
        <p style="height: 120px; font-size: 18px">
            {{item.ItemDescription}}
        </p>
    </article>
    <hr />

</div>
</div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent">
<div class="modal-body">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <img src="{{'data:image/jpg;base64,'+item.Image}}" style="height:150px; width:150px;">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

</div>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.currentItem = null;
$scope.getIceDesignImage = function (item) {
    $scope.currentItem = item;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            currentItem: function () {
                return $scope.currentItem;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone who stumbles upon this (like I did), the img tag is malformed. It should look like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{item.Image}}" style="height:150px; width:150px;">
```